# Need IronPython Code to output Filtering Scheme in Spotfire

Tags: filtering, ironpython, spotfire

I want to print the "name" of the filtering scheme that is specific for each page of my dashboard.

For instance, page 1 of the dashboard may have a filtering scheme named "Filter Scheme 1" and page 2 has "Filter Scheme 2".  I have code that outputs ALL of the Filtering Schemes but I cannot figure out how to associate a specific scheme to the page it sits on.

```
for pg in Document.Pages:  
  print pg.Title                # the page name  
  myPanel = pg.FilterPanel  
  print myPanel.Title           # output is the word: Filters  
  # THIS IS WHERE I WOULD WANT THE FILTERING SCHEME NAME TO APPEAR
  print myPanel.Visible         # output: True  
  print myPanel.Context         # output:  Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Filters.FilterPanel  
  print myPanel.TypeId          # TypeIdentifier:Spotfire.FilterPanel  
  print myPanel.FilteringSchemeReference  
  for i in range(myPanel.TableGroups.Count):  
    for gcObj in myPanel.TableGroups[i].FilterCollectionReference:  
      myFilter= myPanel.TableGroups[i].GetFilter(gcObj.Name)  
      if myFilter.Visible:  
         szCanSee = ' <Visible>'  
      else:  
         szCanSee = ' <Hidden>'  
      print myFilter.FilterReference.ToString() + szCanSee
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the DataFilteringSelection class which you can find in the api here: http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/html/AllMembers_T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_DataFilteringSelection.htm

I've trimmed down your code to just the section asked about as you may need to revise the rest a little as 'myPanel' will no longer be a FilterPanel.

```
  for pg in Document.Pages:  
    print pg.Title                # the page name  
    myPanel = pg.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference
    print myPanel.Name           # output is the filter name
```

To test this I created a file with 4 pages: Introduction, Solution 1, Solution 2 and Page; and 2 filters: Filtering scheme (1) and Filtering scheme (2). Everything used Filtering scheme (1) except Solution 2 which used Filtering scheme (2).

Here is my output:

```
>     Introduction
>     Filtering scheme (1)
>     Solution 1
>     Filtering scheme (1)
>     Solution 2
>     Filtering scheme (2)
>     Page
>     Filtering scheme (1)
```